# Getting Unsupported SignatureAndHashAlgorithm error after adding TLS 1.2 in Websphere 8.5.5.10

Tags: java, spring, tls1.2, websphere-8

My Java 1.8, Spring 4 webservice is trying to access an external website which requires TLS 1.2. I have deployed my service on Websphere 8.5.5.10 and have made all the changes required to add TLS 1.2 mentioned here- 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS2L6K_5.0.0/com.ibm.rational.relm.install.doc/topics/t_enable_tls1.2_was.html

I am getting the below error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https website": Unsupported SignatureAndHashAlgorithm in ServerKeyExchange message**; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Unsupported SignatureAndHashAlgorithm in ServerKeyExchange message
[10/3/17 11:39:10:600 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https website": Unsupported SignatureAndHashAlgorithm in ServerKeyExchange message; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Unsupported SignatureAndHashAlgorithm in ServerKeyExchange message
[10/3/17 11:39:10:600 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:666)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:601 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:601 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:601 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at org.kp.hrts.casemessage.adaptor.AuthServiceAdaptor.get(AuthServiceAdaptor.java:86)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:601 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at org.kp.hrts.casemessage.processor.FulfillmentCaseProcessor.sendRequest(FulfillmentCaseProcessor.java:70)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:601 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at org.kp.hrts.casemessage.listener.CaseMessageListener.onMessage(CaseMessageListener.java:57)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:601 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:721)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:601 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:681)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:601 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:651)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:601 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:601 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:601 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1166)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:601 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:601 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1055)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:602 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:602 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Unsupported SignatureAndHashAlgorithm in ServerKeyExchange message
[10/3/17 11:39:10:602 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.x$k.<init>(x$k.java:77)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:602 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.D.a(D.java:649)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:602 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.C.r(C.java:44)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:602 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.C.a(C.java:184)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:602 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.as.a(as.java:481)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:602 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.as.i(as.java:130)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:602 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.as.a(as.java:483)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:602 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.as.startHandshake(as.java:160)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:602 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.WSSocket.startHandshake(WSSocket.java:414)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:602 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:12)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:603 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:15)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:603 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.connect(b.java:64)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:603 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:78)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:603 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:603 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:603 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:652)
[10/3/17 11:39:10:603 PDT] 000000a4 SystemErr     R     ... 14 more
```

Any inputs would be appreciated!

Comment: What signature algorithm does your servers certificate use?

Comment: Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA
I found this in the server logs. Hope this helps.

Comment: The instructions you are following sound like you are enabling SP800-131a.  If all you need is to use TLSv1.2 you do not need to enable SP800-131a.   It could be that SP800-131a disabled some algorithm spring is using.  Unfortunately it does now say what.    If you do not need SP800-131a disable it and enable TLSv1.2 on the SSL configurations.  Info can be found here https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/206952/how-do-i-configure-websphere-application-server-ss.html

Comment: Thanks @Alaine. I'll try it.

Comment: @Alaine it worked. Also instead of using TLS v1.2 I switched to SSL_TLSv2 and my application is working fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alaine suggested, the problem was the additional steps given in the link which were enabling SP800-131a. 
I followed the steps in the link suggested: 
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/206952/how-do-i-configure-websphere-application-server-ss.html

Also after talking to the IBM team, it was suggested that I use SSL_TLSv2 instead of TLSv1.2 since SSL_TLSv2 supports SSL and TLS 1.x.

Hope this helps someone!